# How to forward ports automatically in java server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

My question is how can I forward a port automatically in a server.

If anyone knows the game "Minecraft" the user have an option to create a server so anyone can join.

Now what I didn't get is how the server automatically forward the port.

Currently i do not have any code to show.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You can't create a port forwarder automatically in Java. Running a server is not creating a port forwarder, it's creating a server that listens on some port(s).

Comment: First of all thank you for answering. But how does Minecraft server works? I mean how the people connect to the server? Someone needs to create the server in his Computer. and this requires port forwarding. when I played Minecraft i didn't need to port forward. it just connect me to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What minecraft does is creates a local port that is listening for connections. I think what you are asking though is how does the other user get through your router to your server. The answer to that is it uses UPnP to tell your router what ports to forward from the wider Internet.

If you want to implement something similar, look for UPnP libraries for Java or whatever language you are writing in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.